# Next.js application - Download word file from Azure blob storage is corrupted

Tags: next.js, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded the word file in azure blobstorage.

I am trying to download the word file in next.js application. Word file got downloaded. While opening the word in MS Word, It shows the below error,

[image]

Here my api code,

```
import { dataFound, dataNotFound } from '@/helpers/api-result';
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob'; 

export const GET = async (request: any) => {
  try {
    const url = new URL(request.url)
    const fileName = url.searchParams.get('fileName') as string;  
    let connectionString = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
    let containerName = "xxxxxxxx"
    const blobServiceClient:any = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString!);
    const containerClient:any = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blobClient:any = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
    const blobDownloadResponse = await blobClient.download();
    let blobStream:any = await blobDownloadResponse.readableStreamBody;
 
      const headers = {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`,
        'Content-Type': blobDownloadResponse.contentType
      };
      const data = {
        status: 200,
        headers,
        body: blobStream
      };
      return data ? dataFound(data):dataNotFound(null)
   
  } catch (error) {
    return {
        status: 500,
        body: 'An error occurred while downloading the file.'
      };
  }
}
```

and my jsx code,

```
  const data = await axios.get("/api/download", { params: { attachmentPath: attachmentPath,fileName:originalFileName },  
                responseType: "blob",
              });
             
            const blobContent = data.data;
            
            if (data.status) {
                const blob = new Blob([blobContent], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" });
                const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = blobUrl;
                a.download = originalFileName;
                a.click();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
            }
```

I have updated the content type 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' and tested, same issue after that also.

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Why are you converting the binary data to string?

Comment: @GauravMantri , can you give me other ways to download

Comment: Try converting the data as buffer and download that buffer.

Comment: Tried to download from buffer, Same issue exists

Comment: Please edit your question and include the updated code. Also, when you directly download the file, are you able to open it properly?

Comment: code updated, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word files are binary files, converting them to a string and then back to a blob might cause corruption. I tried below code to download word blob file from Azure storage to handle the binary data properly.

I uploaded a word file to my storage container at Azure portal like below,

[image]

**Code** :

**pages/api/download.js** :

```js
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { fileName } = req.query;
    const connectionString = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;
    const containerName = '<container_name>'; 

    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);

    const blobDownloadResponse = await blobClient.download();
    const blobStream = blobDownloadResponse.readableStreamBody;

    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');

    blobStream.pipe(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while downloading the file.' });
  }
};
```

**pages/index.js** :

```js
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  const downloadFile = async () => {
    try {
      const fileName = '<wordfile_name>.docx'; 
      const response = await fetch(`/api/download?fileName=${fileName}`);

      if (response.ok) {
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      } else {
        console.error('Error downloading file:', response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={downloadFile}>Download Word File</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**components/DownloadButton.js** :

```js
import React from 'react';

const DownloadButton = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>Download Word File</button>
  );
};

export default DownloadButton;
```

**.env.local** :

```js
NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=<connec_string>
```

**package.json** :

```json
{
  "name": "nextjs-azure-blob-download",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Next.js application for downloading Word files from Azure Blob Storage",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.15.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "next": "^11.1.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

**Output** :

The next js app runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above URL, I downloaded the blob file in the browser as below,

[image]

Then, I opened the downloaded blob, I can see the data in the word file as below,

[image]

Comment: i tried the solution. I am getting error in api 
"error TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function"

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy Have you installed the correct versions of the required packages and dependencies in your environment?

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy I updated my answer with **package.json**. Can you try that once?

Comment: My project is Nextjs 13.  I am trying the add content type in api response.  it is allowing me to add

Comment: Hi @Desari Kamali, what about Next.js 14 with App Router Handlers. it seems like a streamable response cannot be provided... or at least the Request/Response objects do not provide the methods that have been used in your solution...