# Next.js 14 App router download file with Azure Storage Blob - BlobServiceClient with Connection String

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage, next.js14

I had a hard time figuring out how to download from a Blob Storage with limited Access Levels using NextJs 14 with App Router.
In my case it was because Typescript acted a bit bizzare when it came to return SearchParameters and instanciate a Response object with a readable stream.

Infact, while passing the readableStream to the Response constructor, like this:

```
    const blobStream = blobDownloadResponse.readableStreamBody;
    return new Response(blobStream as any, {
```

Typescript complained that

> Argument of type 'ReadableStream | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BodyInit | null | undefined'.
> Type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to type 'BodyInit | null | undefined'.

This is a lie, and simply having TS shut up with `any` solved the issue, and the download actually works:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    const filename = (req as any).nextUrl.searchParams.get('fileName')
    const connString = process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNSTRING
    const instance = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connString);
    const containerClient = instance.getContainerClient(process.env.ZIP_CONTAINER);
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(filename!);
    const blobDownloadResponse = await blobClient.download();
    const blobStream = blobDownloadResponse.readableStreamBody;
    return new Response(blobStream as any, {
      headers: {
        "content-disposition": `attachment; filename="${filename}"`,
        "Content-Type": "application/zip"
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: 'error occurred while downloading the file.' },
      {status:500}
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) Web Api Doc, the constructor can accept a ReadableStream, like the one returned by the [BlobDownloadResponseParsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobdownloadresponseparsed?view=azure-node-latest) interface, yet Typescript came out with this error:

```
Argument of type 'ReadableStream | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BodyInit | null | undefined'.
Type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to type 'BodyInit | null | undefined'.
```

which led me to errors, misunderstanding and time waste.

```
return new Response(blobStream as any, {
```

did the trick for me.
I know it's *baaaaad* to use `any` in TS (in that case one might as well just use simple JS instead) but i could not figure out another solution.

I used as reference:

- [How to download a file on Next.js using an API route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490546/how-to-download-a-file-on-next-js-using-an-api-route)
- [Next.js application - Download word file from Azure blob storage is corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028643/next-js-application-download-word-file-from-azure-blob-storage-is-corrupted)
- [How to Implement Download Files in NextJS using an API Route](https://reacthustle.com/blog/how-to-implement-download-files-in-nextjs-using-an-api-route?expand_article=1)